# python wont import can module in rc.local

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, rc.local

I want to automate my python script which controls devices through CAN. I can start script simply from terminal, but I dont want to do that every time. So I put `nohup python /home/pi/script.py &` in rc.local - did not work. I tried putting print('1') just after `import can` to find out that it never happens. I even put `time.sleep(60)` to make sure everything loads before starting my script - still nothing. Nohup does not show '1' - only '0' which is right before `import can`:

```
import time
time.sleep(60)
print('0')
import can
print('1')
```

Comment: Did you install `can` only for your user? Have your script write to a log file (with `nohup python /home/pi/script.py 2>&1 > logfile`) to see what errors occur

Comment: thanks. I installed can with pip in sudo su - now theres other problem (also with can and sudo) - I guess ill look for other way to launch script on boot